# Navigating IE Dynamic Drop Down Boxes with VBA (Excel)

Tags: jquery, html, vba, excel, internet-explorer-10

I'm currently working on a project to automate some data collection that's currently being done manually.

The data is collected from a website with a simple ctrl + a -> ctrl + c -> ctrl + v series of commands to paste it into an excel document. I've already done a lot of work to automate validations via Excel, but I've run into a hiccup trying to automate the data collection.

At this point I can open up IE, navigate to the webpage, login and then open the correct page from there. My issue is that there are then 6 drop down menus that must be filled before the data can be pulled. Three of the menus are no issue as they have set variables; the issue is with the other three which contain dynamic lists. Here is some of the source code for these menus:

```
*other menus*
                        <td align="right" nowrap="nowrap" class="filterItemName">&nbsp;FG BA:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="CAId" onchange="ChangeFG(); return false;" class="blacksmallnormal">
                            <option value='-1'>Please wait...</option>
                        </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
*other menus*
```

Now, I have basically zero experience with website code (html? java? no clue) and honestly only a few weeks with VBA, so I have pretty much no clue what this means. I tried to grab what's relevant but there's a lot of code. I'm guessing that it has something to do with this function, though:

```
    function ChangeFG()
{
    var objSC = document.getElementById("SCId");
    var objCA = document.getElementById("CAId");

    if (objSC && objCA) {
        var Arr = new Array();
        Arr["SC"] = objSC[objSC.selectedIndex].value;
        Arr["CA"] = objCA[objCA.selectedIndex].value;
        if(Arr["CA"] == "-1")
        {
            alert("Please choose BA");
            return;
        }
        Arr["GetJustFG"] = 1;
        UpdateJustDropDown("<option value='-1'>Please wait...</option>", "FG");
        var url = ".....";
        SendAJAXCommand('UPDT_FLG', url, UpdateFGWithData, "FG", true, Arr);
    }
```

First, I have no clue how to view the dynamic lists for these menus aside from clicking on them myself; I'm not sure how to determine which is the option I need. Secondly, when I have just stuck a value in for the list the menu ends up blank.

Here is some code of what I've been trying:

```
Private Sub RetrieveData_Click()

Dim appIE As Object
Dim website As String
Dim UsNa As Object
Dim PsWd As Object
Dim ElementCol As Object
Dim btnInput As Object

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
appIE.Visible = True

website = "https://www...."

With appIE
    .Navigate website
    .Visible = True
End With

Do While appIE.Busy
Loop

*Login here*

'navigate to actual page to get data from
appIE.Navigate ("https://www...")

Do While appIE.Busy
Loop

DoEvents

Set ElementCol = appIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("select")

For Each btnInput In ElementCol
    If btnInput.Name = "SCId" Then
        btnInput.Value = "8"
        Exit For
    End If
Next

Do While appIE.Busy
Loop

Set ElementCol = appIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("select")

For Each btnInput In ElementCol
    If btnInput.Name = "Direction" Then
        btnInput.Value = "0"
    Exit For
    End If
Next

Do While appIE.Busy
Loop

For Each btnInput In ElementCol
    If btnInput.Name = "FG" Then
        btnInput.FireEvent ("onChange")
        btnInput.Value = "6009"
    Exit For
    End If
Next
```

I know it's messy code and whatnot; the plan is to clean it up after I figure out how to make it work. It's certainly gotten messier as I kept iterating on this issue.

Anyway, any insight on how to make this work would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There are no choices in the select you posted the HTML for, so it looks like they're being loaded dynamically.  Instead of using "view source" to get the HTML it might be more useful to use the IE Developer tools (F12) to try to get the actual source (ie. not the source as delivered from the server, but the HTML after it has been updated by the script on the page) Use the "magnifying glass" tool to view the HTML for the select list - if it has choices then you should be able to see the underlying HTML.

Comment: Wow, thanks Tim! Using F12 let me get into the code and see the actual options! Will update if I have any more issues, but I seem to be able to now properly fill the menus.

Comment: @TimWilliams Hi Tim, can you please take a look at my issue with VBE IE (I have tried few things already but no luck - please see Questions section on my profile). Much obliged